# How can I use Webhook to Edit the sheet while using Security Filter in appsheet.?

Tags: google-appsheet

Hi i have create a POS system in appsheet. And for that I have create a webhook which deduct the Available Stocks and put the value of new available stock in Available stocks but now when I used Security filter it is not editing that Stocks can someone help me with how can I use my webhook while using Security Filter?